# How does one represent multiple threads in a structure/flowchart

Tags: chart.js, structure, flowchart

I have been tasked with creating a structure/flowchart for some client-server and start-up processes in our organization's software. A lot of our processes run concurrently as they have an impact on one another. How is this traditionally represented in the flow chart?
description the program :
A server having more than one thread is known as Multithreaded Server. When a client sends the
request, a thread is generated through which a user can communicate with the server. You need to
implement a server-client program to generate multiple threads to accept multiple requests from
multiple clients at the same time **(in parallel)**.
Let many clients work on the same input data as follows:

- An integer matrix of size 10×10 is randomly generated (numbers between 1-10) and stored on
  the server side. - Each client requests a specific service from the server:

1. Client 1: Matrix summation
2. Client 2: Matrix sort (ascendingly)
3. Client 3: Find the maximum number
4. Client 4: Transpose the matrix
5. Client 5: Count the repeated number (ex: number 1 is repeated 5 times)
   ***I JUST NEED TO structure/flowchart***

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I miss-understood the question, but I think the diagram you are looking for is either a sequence diagram or an activity diagram.

Draw.io is a tool that can draw this, and has examples at https://drawio-app.com/create-uml-sequence-diagrams-in-draw-io/

Hope this points you in the right direction.